# Measure time it takes to pass the parameters to the function

Tags: c++, time, arguments

Is there a way to measure how much time the function has spent by passing the parameters? My thought is to measure the body of the function and the whole function itself. Is that the right approach? **Pseudo code below:**

```
int main(){
  int start = time.now();
  // passing by value
  int timeOfFunc = foo(vector<my_object> huge_vector, vector<my_object2> huge_vector2);
  int end = time.now();
  int timeSpentPassingArgs = (end - start) - timeOfFunc; // getting time it takes to pass the argument?
}

int foo(vector<my_object> huge_vector, vector<my_object2> huge_vector2)
{
 int start = time.now();
 // body of the foo function
 int end = time.now();
 return (end - start);
}
```

Comment: `foo(vector<my_object> huge_vector, vector<my_object2> huge_vector2)` That's not how you call a function though.

Comment: Why do you need to measure how long it takes to pass the parameters?  If you want to time how long it takes to make a copy just time making a copy.  Otherwise just pass "large" objects by reference/const reference/rvalue reference and don't make a copy to begin with.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thus the phrase "Pseudo code below"

Comment: @WhozCraig Didn't see the pseudo, you're right.

Comment: @NathanOliver The objects passed in vector have in real app an underlying memory management and it appears to be faulty when the object is passed by reference or by value to a function. This seems to be the easiest way to find out if something dodgy is happening in the first place, before put into futher investigation.

Comment: I've never seen someone debug by timing things before.  Almost sounds like you should make an [mcve] of the problem and ask why that doesn't work instead of this.

Comment: @NathanOliver There is a lot in the background. The Minimal, Complete and Ve... is not possible since you dont have the access to the actual memory managment layer used in the system. I was hoping for something like "If I would have wanted to measure this - and god knows why - this should work"

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want to measure this?   Practically, the results will be affected by a lot of things, such as how aggressive the compiler is (configured to be) with inlining and the precision of timing.  For example, the compiler may eliminate the overhead of function call completely.   It may recognise, globally, that the two calls of `time.now()` are consecutive, and eliminate one of them.

Comment: @Peter I do believe I have explained enought in the comments above.

Comment: I fail to see how measuring timing of function call overhead is pertinent to chasing down a fault in memory management associated with some object, even if that object is being passed by reference or value to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your approach except that you timings will include the time it takes to call `time.now()` twice in the function.  That should be pretty minor though compared to the cost of the copying.

Another option you can tries follows like (using pseudo code):

```
function(parameters)
{
    return time.now();
}

// calling code
time start = time.now();
time end = function(paramters);
time total_time = end - start;
```

And that should tell you exactly how long it takes to just call the function and copy the parameters.  I'm not sure if the compiler is allowed to/can optimized out an unused copy of the parameters but if it does you should just get a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend printing the assembly language of the function making the call.  This should give you an idea of the work required to pass the variables.

In order to have a meaningful profile, you should measure the time before the function call and the time after and perform over 1E6 iterations.  You can then get an average of the execution time required to call a function.

Another alternative is to look up the *clock cycles* required by each assembly instruction used in the function call.  This may not be accurate due to how the processor executes the assembly language instructions (it may perform in parallel, the code may or may not be in an instruction cache, etc.).

**Edit 1: oscilloscopes**
A good tool to measure performance is an oscilloscope.  In the Embedded Systems area, the code writes to a test point (or LED).  For example, the LED would be turned on before the function call and turned off after the function call.  An oscillocope probe would be attached to the LED.  The o'scope can then be used to measure the duration that the LED is on.  Again, many iterations would need to be performed to get a better average.